# Can't Edit and Continue in Linked files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, edit-and-continue

I have a solution with 8 related projects (which are all C# Windows Desktop Applications--- a utilities suite).  All 8 projects use a pair of class files which are in each project as linked files.
I can set breakpoints in the linked code, and step thru it, but I cannot edit.  When I try, I get the error "Changes are not allowed if the project wasn't built when debugging started."  I've made sure to perform a clean and build before running, but that doesn't help.
Is it not possible to edit linked class files?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question but you can't edit your code during a debugging session. You have to exit it first before editing code.

Comment: @devin no, indeed you can"edit and continue", but there are restrictions.

Comment: I strongly suspect VS can't figure out what tod do if source file is used by more than one project... Since it is in general strange way of sharing code not allowing edit and continue in such case feel reasonable